# Apache spark integration with Airflow running on K8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, airflow, amazon-eks

I am using the helm chart to install Apache Airflow and Spark in the same k8s cluster. However, when I attempt to add spark connection information to the airflow. I am not receiving any spark providers.
Since I am new to this, I don't know how to integrate both the application.

Thanks..

Comment: There is a PR in progress to add `SparkKubernetesOperator` 
 see https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22253
If you can help testing it this would be great for the review process.